# Saving a card to charge a connected stripe account later in EU (using SCA). React & Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

My code is working to save a customer's card and charge them later on my stripe account. However, when I amend the code to charge the card on a connected stripe account, it will not work.

Please note, I am in EU so I must use strong customer authentication - I cannot use tokens.

The relevant frontend code is:

```
        const cardElement = this.props.elements.getElement('card');

    axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/saveCardDetails`, {stripeAccountID: this.props.stripeAccountID}).then(res => {


    this.props.stripe.confirmCardSetup(res.data.client_secret, {
        payment_method: {
    card: cardElement,
  },
    },{
    stripe_account: this.props.stripeAccountID,
    }
).then( confirmCardSetupRes => {..})
```

The relevant backend code is:

```
    //saveCardDetails controller

module.exports = (req, res) => {

    stripe.setupIntents.create().then(intent => {
        console.log('intent.client_secret', intent.client_secret)
        res.send({client_secret: intent.client_secret})
    })
}

//code to charge the saved card
const chargeSavedCard = (customerStripeID, price, currency, eventTitle, applicationFee, organiserstripeAccountID) => {


    stripe.paymentMethods.list({
        customer: customerStripeID,
        type: 'card',
    }).then(paymentMethods => {
        stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: Math.round(price * 100),
            currency: currency,
            customer: customerStripeID,
            payment_method: paymentMethods.data[0].id,
            off_session: true,
            confirm: true,
            application_fee_amount: Math.round(applicationFee)
        }
        ,{
        stripe_account: organiserstripeAccountID,
        }

    ).then(stripeRes => {.......})
```

which is throwing the following error:

```
{ Error: No such PaymentMethod: pm_1G4YYVCFzSpFw85fXVcZj0hX; OAuth key or Stripe-Account header was used but API request was provided with a platform-owned payment method ID. Please ensure that the provided payment method matches the specified account.
```

I don't understand why my code isn't setting up the payment method on the connected account. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the PaymentMethod is created on the Platform account, not on the Connect account.

On your frontend, you should initialize Stripe.js and authenticate as the Connect account: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#adding-the-connected-account-id-to-a-client-side-application
The way you have right now (by passing `{stripe_account: "acct_123"}` as options to `confirmCardSetup`) won't work.

You should also create the SetupIntent on the Connect account, by passing the Stripe-Account header server-side, like you are doing when creating the PaymentIntent: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header

Comment: I have initialized Stripe.js and authenticate as the Connect account using the following code:

`<StripeProvider apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_API_STRIPE_PUBLISH}
 stripeAccount={this.state.userEvent.organiser.stripeAccountID}
>`

And I have changed the backend as you recommended.
My code now looks like this:
`//front end
const cardElement = this.props.elements.getElement('card');

  axios.post(${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/saveCardDetails, {stripeAccountID: this.props.stripeAccountID})
  .then(res => {`

Comment: `this.props.stripe.confirmCardSetup(res.data.client_secret, {
   payment_method: {
        card: cardElement,
      }
  }
    ).then( confirmCardSetupRes => {

  axios.post(${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/purchaseWaitList, {
    paymentMethodID: confirmCardSetupRes.setupIntent.payment_method,

   })



//backend
//saveCardDetails controller
 stripe.setupIntents.create({
  stripe_account: req.body.stripeAccountID,
  }).then(intent => {
  res.send({client_secret: intent.client_secret})
 })`

Comment: `//purchaseWaitListController
stripe.customers.create({payment_method: req.body.paymentMethodID}, {
   stripe_account: purchaser.stripeAccountID}
)`

I am getting the following error message when I try to create the stripe customer:
`{ Error: No such PaymentMethod: pm_1G5WnCLkWPLevtVYti9Q8U76`

Can you see where I am going wrong?

Comment: I'd recommend making sure the `purchaser.stripeAccountID` on your backend is the same as the `this.state.userEvent.organiser.stripeAccountID` , both the Customer and PaymentMethod have to be the same Stripe Account, therefore should be the same account ID